# android import external classes into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, class

I've seen many ways to import my own classes to a project, but they all just say "do this, do that" and there's no explanation of how the thing actually works. I'm used to iPhone development and there i just link the classes from an external folder to the project and i can modify them in the IDE or externally - they will still be linked (that is they are not copied to the project during development, they're merely links to actual files). I was wondering if such a thing is possible on eclipse? Ideally when i add another class to the folder, it should also appear in eclipse if possible.

- i link the external class (without making any copies of it)
- i modify the class, it gets modified for all projects using it
- on build, eclipse automatically includes the file as well

Thanks

Comment: Check out my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079670/how-to-build-a-java-code-library-for-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android library projects is the answer you're looking for. You'll find a good documentation for it here: [Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should set up an  [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).  Once you've done this, you can add references to the library project to as many applications as you need.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i've been looking for